# Find bluetooth local interface name

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to write some scripts to work with the Bluetooth adapter but I need to know the local interface name and I'm not sure how to find it.

I tried an educated guess of `hci1` but that wasn't correct.

Comment: I've now managed to randomly guess it, but I'd still like to know how to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the `bluez` package. It may require some `python` dependencies using `pip`. If you receive any errors about header files from pybluez (which is common), you can find the fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597536/pybluez-installation-in-linux).

```
sudo apt install bluez

man hcitool
```

Comment: Perfect. I'm actually working with Bluez right now.

Answer (score 2):

the following command will show all bluetooth devices:

```
hcitool dev
```